how do i fix "zsh: command not found: brew"
I installed brew on Macintosh 11.7.10
When I run brew from the terminal I get this:
"zsh: command not found: brew"
When I run brew using the path like "MBP bin % /usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew info"
I GET "Do not report this issue: you are running in an unsupported configuration."
HOW DO I INSTALL A SUPPORTED CONFIGURATION?
I RAN THIS "MBP bin % /usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew update && brew upgrade && brew cleanup"
IT RAN WITHOUT ERROR

Is brew installed and configured correctly on your system ? Try running "brew docter" . Also make sure your profile file (~/.zshrc) has brew path set.

At the time of this writing, macOS 11 Big Sur is no longer supported by either Apple or Homebrew.  A supported configuration would need to comply with the requirements set forth in the installation instructions:
https://docs.brew.sh/Installation#macos-requirements
At the time of this writing, the minimum configuration requires macOS 12 Monterey. Homebrew may still be usable, but the bottles downloaded may or may not work, and there is zero help available from the Homebrew team in getting the tool to work on an obsoleted macOS version.
Apple has been supporting the most recent 3 major system versions. Homebrew follows this trend. Currently macOS 14, 13, and 12 (Sonoma, Ventura, Monterey) are supported.
Not being able to run brew from the command line could indicate a problem with the installation. That should be accomplished by following the instructions at https://brew.sh
